# What is a “visual metaphor”?

Tags: meaning

I recently completed some pseudoscience based team training designed to define each team members personality.

I've been asked to provide a “visual metaphor” with a blank page to do so on the feedback form.

Only problem is I can't find a decent definition after having looked around (Wiktionary, Wikipedia, Google Define etc.). Would appreciate a straight forward definition.

Comment: http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/vismeterm.htm

Comment: how about [just plain google?](https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+pun)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You're welcome.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhh......... ummmmmmmmmm....... I now feel as informed as I did looking at the top results on Google image search or reading this definition on ChaCha http://www.chacha.com/question/what-is-a-visual-metaphor

Comment: Simplified: it means using a picture (of something completely different) to describe something.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff I think I got it now. Your about.com link above was helpful.

Comment: @JeffSahol I took the liberty of linking the image to your about.com link, I hope you don't mind :-)

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the smart aleck answer but it was too much to pass up.

Comment: This is a subset of visual metaphors, called 'visual puns'.

Comment: I took the further liberty of downloading the photo, cropping the ugly white edge off of the bottom, and re-uploading it.